# Okta OpenID Auth for Users' Server-side Applications

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid, okta

I have an Okta account which performs Auth using OpenID and OAuth 2.0.

There is a single web application users can login to and Auth is verified on my API using the *id_token* and *access_token* generated by the Okta Sign-in widget (web application).

My users will need to also perform API requests directly from their servers rather than the UI; however, the sign-in widget requires a URL redirect to receive tokens.

**How can users of the application retrieve tokens from server-side code to be able to make authenticated requests to my API?**

Answer (score 0):

Okta supports a `Resource Owner Password` flow which might suit you needs, because it allows to request user credentials directly from okta by making a rest api call, like this:

```
POST https://youroktadomain.com/oauth2/default/v1/token?grant_type=password&username=user1&password=11111&scope=openid
```

Okta provides a [very good step-by-step guide here](https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/implementing-authentication/password/#_2-using-the-resource-owner-password-flow) to setup a `Resource Owner Password`.

When you complete these steps you'll have two options:

1. Create an okta wrapper WebApi application. It will expose a login endpoint that your users will call (input will be okta username/password). Under the curtain this app calls okta (via rest call), receives access_token and returns it to the user
2. Share direct okta call to your users

The first option sounds preferable because it gives you some control, while the second doesn't require any effort but reveals your internals.